# how to remove disable property from button in jquery(only after all dropdown value is selected )?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am able to remove disable `property` from button using this

```
$('[data-bankdetail="btnbankdetail"]').prop("disabled", false);
```

But I want to remove this property from button only when user select  values from dropdown (till it should be disable).In other words when user select values from first three dropdown then only after this is remove disable property

Here is my code: https://jsbin.com/fasusajowi/edit?html,output

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<form>
    <span><select data-bank-list="banksname">
                                    <option value="0" disabled="true" selected="true">Select Bank</option>
         <option value="1">A</option>
         <option value="2">B</option>
                                </select></span>
    <span><select data-state-list="statename">
                                    <option value="0" disabled="true" selected="true">Select State</option>
        <option value="3">C</option>
         <option value="4">D</option>
                                </select></span>
    <span><select data-district-list="districtname">
                                    <option value="0" disabled="true" selected="true">Select District</option>
           <option value="5">E</option>
         <option value="6">F</option>
                                </select></span>

    <button class="ifsc_getbankbtn" data-bankdetail="btnbankdetail" disabled="true">Get Bank Details</button>
</form>
  <script>
  $(function(){
    //$('[data-bankdetail="btnbankdetail"]').prop("disabled", false);
  })
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: so add an onchange event to the select element's and see if they are all selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you need to add a `change` event handler to the `select` elements, which checks to see if they all have a value selected from them. You can then set the button's `disabled` property as required, something like this:

```js
$('select').on('change', function() {
  var $empty = $('select').filter(function() {
    return !$(this).val();
  }); 
  $('[data-bankdetail="btnbankdetail"]').prop("disabled", $empty.length != 0);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.js"></script>

<form>
  <span>
    <select data-bank-list="banksname">
      <option value="0" disabled="true" selected="true">Select Bank</option>
      <option value="1">A</option>
      <option value="2">B</option>
    </select>
  </span>
  <span>
    <select data-state-list="statename">
     <option value="0" disabled="true" selected="true">Select State</option>
     <option value="3">C</option>
     <option value="4">D</option>
    </select>
  </span>
  <span>
    <select data-district-list="districtname">
      <option value="0" disabled="true" selected="true">Select District</option>
     <option value="5">E</option>
     <option value="6">F</option>
   </select>
  </span>
  <button class="ifsc_getbankbtn" data-bankdetail="btnbankdetail" disabled="true">Get Bank Details</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function enableButton() {
  var dropdows = $('select option:selected:not([value="0"])');
  $('[data-bankdetail="btnbankdetail"]').prop("disabled", dropdows.length < 3);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <form onchange="enableButton()">
    <span>
        <select data-bank-list="banksname">
          <option value="0" disabled="true" selected="true">Select Bank</option>
         <option value="1">A</option>
         <option value="2">B</option>
        </select>
    </span>
    
    <span>
      <select data-state-list="statename">
        <option value="0" disabled="true" selected="true">Select State</option>
        <option value="3">C</option>
        <option value="4">D</option>
       </select>
    </span>
    
    <span>
      <select data-district-list="districtname">
        <option value="0" disabled="true" selected="true">Select District</option>
        <option value="5">E</option>
        <option value="6">F</option>
      </select>
     </span>

    <button class="ifsc_getbankbtn" data-bankdetail="btnbankdetail" disabled="true">Get Bank Details</button>
  </form>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      //$('[data-bankdetail="btnbankdetail"]').prop("disabled", false);
    })
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#s1, #s2, #s3').change(function() {
  var ids = ['s1', 's2', 's3'];
  for (var index = 0, id; id = ids[index]; index++) {
    if ($('#' + id).prop('selectedIndex') < 1) {
      $('[data-bankdetail="btnbankdetail"]').prop("disabled", true);
      return;
    }
  }

  $('[data-bankdetail="btnbankdetail"]').prop("disabled", false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.js"></script>

<form>
  <span>
    <select data-bank-list="banksname" id="s1">
      <option value="0" disabled="true" selected="true">Select Bank</option>
      <option value="1">A</option>
      <option value="2">B</option>
    </select>
  </span>
  <span>
    <select data-state-list="statename" id="s2">
     <option value="0" disabled="true" selected="true">Select State</option>
     <option value="3">C</option>
     <option value="4">D</option>
    </select>
  </span>
  <span>
    <select data-district-list="districtname" id="s3">
      <option value="0" disabled="true" selected="true">Select District</option>
     <option value="5">E</option>
     <option value="6">F</option>
   </select>
  </span>
  <button class="ifsc_getbankbtn" data-bankdetail="btnbankdetail" disabled="true">Get Bank Details</button>
</form>
```